# Multiple rows printing from database

Tags: c#, sql, database, wml

After querying for data from a database
I used the datareader to fill an array. as the following.

```
connection.Open();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();

_firstname = reader[0].ToString();
_Year = reader[1].ToString();
_coursename = reader[2].ToString();
_credits = reader[3].ToString();
_mark = reader[4].ToString();
_firstname2 = reader[5].ToString();

reader.Close();
```

I
But the result show as below

```
1 - Sam Bons 
2- 2012 
3- DDD 
4- 3 
5- 80
```

How can I perform a loop to get **all the results** from the DB and print it out ?

thank you

---

I did it as so **Thank you Ann**

```
result = string.Empty;
                int counter = 1;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    _firstname = reader[0].ToString();
                    _Year = reader[1].ToString();
                    _coursename = reader[2].ToString();
                    _credits = reader[3].ToString();
                    _mark = reader[4].ToString();

                    result += string.Format("{5} - {0}{1}{2}{3}{4} </br>  ",
                        _firstname,
                        _Year,
                        _coursename,
                        _credits,
                        _mark,
                        counter);
                    counter++;

                }
                Response.Write(result);

                reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're not actually putting anything in an array, as you stated.  You're just setting what look to be local variables.

If your question is about the syntax of a loop, it would be like this:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   // set your variables
   // do something with the variables
}
```

Put that between your ExecuteReader call and your reader.Close() call.